# Is it possible to format logs to access the file and line in visual studio code integrated terminal?

Tags: logging, visual-studio-code

Is there a given format in visual studio code to access the origin of a log by clicking its line?

In my current setup I run scripts in the integrated terminal.

I would like to be able to click on a log entry and directly go to the file and line.

Is there a specific format I should use to make my logs clickable from the VS-Code integrated terminal?

Answer (score 0):

From here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yxkt8b26.aspx

"If the output of a custom build step or build event is formatted correctly, users get the following benefits:

- Warnings and errors are counted in the Output window.
- Output appears in the Task List window.
- Clicking on the output in the Output window displays the appropriate
  topic.
- F1 operations are enabled in the Task List window or Output window.

The format of the output should be:

```
{filename (line# [, column#]) | toolname} :
[any text] {error | warning} code####:localizable string
[ any text ]
```

Where:

```
{a | b} is a choice of either a or b.
[ccc] is an optional string or parameter."
```

Comment: I tried this to no avail, the integrated terminal doesn't allow logged messages to be transformed to links to the source files. At least not on OS X.

Comment: Ohhh, VS Code. Missed that essential part.